# Django: Top navigation bar refreshes (flickers) when clicking on menu items

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have developed a Django app with a fixed top navbar, but it sometimes flickers / refreshes when clicking the menu items. Have I made a mistake in extending the templates or it is something else causing this?

Here is the app deployed that you can see it: http://azeribocorp.pythonanywhere.com/index/

**__base.html:**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        {% block meta_tags %}{% endblock meta_tags%}
        <title>
            {% block title %}Azeribo Tracking{% endblock title %} 
        </title>
        {% block stylesheets %}         {% endblock stylesheets %}  
        {% block js %}                  {% endblock js %}               
    </head>

    <body>
        <header class="topnavbar" id="TNB" >
            {% include 'aztracker/_topnavbar.html' %}
        </header>
        <div id="main" role="main">
            <div class="container">
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock content %}
            </div>
        </div> {# /#main #}
    </body>
</html>
```

**search_form.html:**

```
{% extends 'aztracker/__base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}

{% block stylesheets %}                 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/__main.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/search_form.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% block main_col %}
        <section class="search_section">
            <form  method="POST" action="/search/">         
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input required type="search" placeholder="Country or Code" name="search_input_field" id="search_input">
                <button id="search_btn" class="flat_button">Search</button>
            </form>
        </section>

        <!-- view all country codes link -->
        <div class="wrapper">
            <a id="list_of_all_countries_link" href="/countries/"> List of All Countries and Codes </a>
        </div>
    {% endblock main_col %} 
{% endblock content %}
```

**_topnavbar.html:**

```
{% load static %}
{% load staticfiles %}


{% block stylesheets %} 
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-iso.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/_topnavbar.css' %}">
{% endblock %}


<!--Top Navigation-->
<nav role="navigation" class="nav" id="topnav">
    <ul class="nav-items">
        <li class="{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'index' %}
                nav-item active
            {% else %}
                nav-item
            {% endif %}"> 
            <a href={% url 'index' %} class='nav-link'><span>Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <!--<li class="nav-item">
            <a href={% url 'index' %} class="nav-link" ><span>Home</span></a>
        </li>-->
        <li class="{% if 'track_containers' in  request.resolver_match.url_name  %}
                nav-item active
            {% else %}
                nav-item
            {% endif %}"> 
            <a href={% url 'track_containers_import_data' %} class='nav-link'><span>Track Containers</span></a>
        </li>
            <nav class="submenu">
                <ul class="submenu-items">
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Product #1</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Product #2</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Product #3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </li> 
        <li class="{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'search' %}
                nav-item active
            {% else %}
                nav-item 
            {% endif %}"> 
            <a href={% url 'search' %} class='nav-link'><span>Search</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'report' %}
                nav-item active
            {% else %}
                nav-item
            {% endif %}"> 
            <a href={% url 'report' %} class='nav-link'><span>Report</span></a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="dd-more"><span>More</span></a>
            <nav class="submenu">
                <ul class="submenu-items">
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href="{% url 'about' %}" class="submenu-link">About</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href={% url 'contact_us' %} class="submenu-link">Contact us</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu-item"><hr class="submenu-seperator" /></li>
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Support</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">FAQs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </li> 

        <!--
        <li class="{% if 'more' in request.resolver_match.url_name  %}
                nav-item dropdown active
            {% else %}
                nav-item dropdown
            {% endif %}"> 
            <a href='#'><span>More</span></a> <!- -js will take care of dropping the menu - ->
            <nav class="submenu">
                <ul class="submenu-items">
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href={% url 'about'%} class="submenu-link">About</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href={% url 'contact_us'%} class="submenu-link">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu-item"><hr class="submenu-seperator" /></li>
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href={% url 'support'%} class="submenu-link">Support</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href={% url 'faqs'%} class="submenu-link">FAQs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </li> -->
    </ul>
</nav>

{% block js %}
    <script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'js/_topnavbar.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock js %}
```

**__base.html [edit 1]:**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        {% block meta_tags %}{% endblock meta_tags%}
        <title>
            {% block title %}Azeribo Tracking{% endblock title %} 
        </title>

        <!-- styles and js required for topnavbar -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-iso.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/_topnavbar.css' %}">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'js/_topnavbar.js' %}"></script>

        {% block stylesheets %}     {% endblock stylesheets %}  

        {% block js %}                  {% endblock js %}               
    </head>

    <body>
        <header class="topnavbar" id="TNB">
            {% block topnavbar %}
                {% include 'aztracker/_topnavbar.html' %}
            {% endblock topnavbar %}
        </header>
        <div id="main" role="main">
            <div class="container">
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock content %}
            </div>
        </div> {# /#main #}
    </body>
</html>
```

**search_form.html [edit 1]:**

```
{% extends 'aztracker/__base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}

{% block stylesheets %}                 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/__main.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/search_form.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% block main_col %}
        <section class="search_section">
            <form  method="POST" action="/search/">         
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input required type="search" placeholder="Country or Code" name="search_input_field" id="search_input">
                <button id="search_btn" class="flat_button">Search</button>
            </form>
        </section>

        <!-- view all country codes link -->
        <div class="wrapper">
            <a id="list_of_all_countries_link" href="/countries/"> List of All Countries and Codes </a>
        </div>
    {% endblock main_col %} 
{% endblock content %}
```

**_topnavbar.html [edit 1]:**

```
{% load static %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block topnavbar %}
    <!--Top Navigation-->
    <nav role="navigation" class="nav" id="topnav">
        <ul class="nav-items">
            <li class="{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'index' %}
                    nav-item active
                {% else %}
                    nav-item
                {% endif %}"> 
                <a href={% url 'index' %} class='nav-link'><span>Home</span></a>
            </li>
            <!--<li class="nav-item">
                <a href={% url 'index' %} class="nav-link" ><span>Home</span></a>
            </li>-->
            <li class="{% if 'track_containers' in  request.resolver_match.url_name  %}
                    nav-item active
                {% else %}
                    nav-item
                {% endif %}"> 
                <a href={% url 'track_containers_import_data' %} class='nav-link'><span>Track Containers</span></a>
            </li>
                <nav class="submenu">
                    <ul class="submenu-items">
                        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Product #1</a></li>
                        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Product #2</a></li>
                        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Product #3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </li> 
            <li class="{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'search' %}
                    nav-item active
                {% else %}
                    nav-item 
                {% endif %}"> 
                <a href={% url 'search' %} class='nav-link'><span>Search</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'report' %}
                    nav-item active
                {% else %}
                    nav-item
                {% endif %}"> 
                <a href={% url 'report' %} class='nav-link'><span>Report</span></a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="dd-more"><span>More</span></a>
                <nav class="submenu">
                    <ul class="submenu-items">
                        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="{% url 'about' %}" class="submenu-link">About</a></li>
                        <li class="submenu-item"><a href={% url 'contact_us' %} class="submenu-link">Contact us</a></li>
                        <li class="submenu-item"><hr class="submenu-seperator" /></li>
                        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Support</a></li>
                        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">FAQs</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </li> 

            <!--
            <li class="{% if 'more' in request.resolver_match.url_name  %}
                    nav-item dropdown active
                {% else %}
                    nav-item dropdown
                {% endif %}"> 
                <a href='#'><span>More</span></a> <!- -js will take care of dropping the menu - ->
                <nav class="submenu">
                    <ul class="submenu-items">
                        <li class="submenu-item"><a href={% url 'about'%} class="submenu-link">About</a></li>
                        <li class="submenu-item"><a href={% url 'contact_us'%} class="submenu-link">Contact</a></li>
                        <li class="submenu-item"><hr class="submenu-seperator" /></li>
                        <li class="submenu-item"><a href={% url 'support'%} class="submenu-link">Support</a></li>
                        <li class="submenu-item"><a href={% url 'faqs'%} class="submenu-link">FAQs</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </li> -->
        </ul>
    </nav>
{% endblock topnavbar %}



{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        {% block meta_tags %}{% endblock meta_tags%}
        <title>
            {% block title %}Azeribo Tracking{% endblock title %} 
        </title>

        <!-- styles and js required for topnavbar -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-iso.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/_topnavbar.css' %}">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        {% block stylesheets %}     {% endblock stylesheets %}  

        {% block js %}                  {% endblock js %}               
    </head>

    <body>
        <header class="topnavbar" id="TNB">
            {% block topnavbar %}
                {% include 'aztracker/_topnavbar.html' %}
            {% endblock topnavbar %}
        </header>
        <div id="main" role="main">
            <div class="container">
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock content %}
            </div>
        </div> {# /#main #}

        {% block extra-js %}
            <script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'js/_topnavbar.js' %}"></script>
        {% endblock extra-js %} 

    </body>
</html>
```

**__base.html [edit 2]:**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        {% block meta_tags %}{% endblock meta_tags%}
        <title>
            {% block title %}Azeribo Tracking{% endblock title %} 
        </title>

        <!-- styles and js required for topnavbar -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-iso.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/_topnavbar.css' %}">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        {% block stylesheets %}     {% endblock stylesheets %}  

        {% block js %}                  {% endblock js %}               
    </head>

    <body>
        <header class="topnavbar" id="TNB">
            {% block topnavbar %}
                {% include 'aztracker/_topnavbar.html' %}
            {% endblock topnavbar %}
        </header>
        <div id="main" role="main">
            <div class="container">
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock content %}
            </div>
        </div> {# /#main #}

        {% block extra-js %}
            <script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'js/_topnavbar.js' %}"></script>
        {% endblock extra-js %} 

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will use WebDeveloperTools/Inspector or similar tools then you will notice that rewrite of *stylesheets* block in _tophavbar.html doesn't work. Js and css are included inside of body.

It happens because you are **including** _topnavbar.html into _base.html (without extension). It means that _topnavbar.html doesn't now anything about *stylesheets* block in _base.html template.

You can move menu js and css to the top template. Second solution is to implement different template inheritance __base.html -> __base_with_menu.html -> search_form.html

P.S. Also you have defined *js* block, so probably you want to include js files inside of it and not in *stylesheets*.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I want to go with the 1st solution, I made changes, but the menu does not appear. I do NOT get any error, just the menu is not there. I will add the edited files and see where I am making a mistake again.

Comment: added the new codes to the question with the tag `[edit 1]`

Comment: @Ibo begin from scratch. Just copy js and css from topnavbar to  _base.html and all the rest leave as it was before. Don't delete include and don't add extend anywhere.

Comment: ok, now with the edit you made, the menu is fixed and does not refresh, but my drop down item on the menu called `More` does not work since the js is not acting. Surprisingly there is no error thrown in the developer tools

Comment: I noticed that when I move `topnavbar.js` to after where there is `include topnavbar` the problem gets resolved. I guess js file needs the whole DOM loaded before. I am not sure if there is any better solution for this?

Comment: @ibo actually it is better practice to put js into end of body instead of head, because you firstly loads DOM and then related js. The page works faster in this case.